# SQL Server evaluates table valued funtion twice

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, database-performance

SQL Server coes up with a very strange execution plan when selecting from a table valued function:

```
DECLARE @buffer float = 55.0
DECLARE @day date = '09.03.2018'
SELECT *
  FROM [dbo].[fct_foo] ( @buffer, @day )
GO
```

The strange thing is that the function seems to be evaluated twice, executing the code inside the function manually is 7 times faster. The first execution of the function estimes EstimateRows="1" and has ActualRows="0".
The second execution of the function estimes EstimateRows="1" and has ActualRows="1992" which is the size of th correct result table.
Any ideas why the evaluation is executed twice? General hints for getting correct row esitmations are also very much appreciated :)
I am aware of another issue described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017793/t-sql-code-is-extremely-slow-when-saved-as-an-inline-table-valued-function), but it does not help with this issue.

[image: the executionplan picture]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ShowPlanXML xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="1.2" Build="11.0.5058.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/showplan">
  <BatchSequence>
    <Batch>
      <Statements>
        <StmtSimple StatementCompId="3" StatementEstRows="1" StatementId="1" StatementOptmLevel="FULL" StatementOptmEarlyAbortReason="GoodEnoughPlanFound" StatementSubTreeCost="0.00328626" StatementText="SELECT *  FROM [dbo].[fct_foo] ( @buffer, @day )&#xD;&#xA;" StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x2247A3EEF95ACB75" QueryPlanHash="0x58FA3B5B0BE3CD9F" RetrievedFromCache="true">
          <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
          <QueryPlan DegreeOfParallelism="1" CachedPlanSize="16" CompileTime="1" CompileCPU="1" CompileMemory="120">
            <MemoryGrantInfo SerialRequiredMemory="0" SerialDesiredMemory="0" />
            <OptimizerHardwareDependentProperties EstimatedAvailableMemoryGrant="131072" EstimatedPagesCached="32768" EstimatedAvailableDegreeOfParallelism="2" />
            <RelOp AvgRowSize="4575" EstimateCPU="2E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Sequence" NodeId="0" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Sequence" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.00328626">
              <OutputList>
                <ColumnReference Database="[db_BA_LSA_QZ]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[fct_foo]" Column="col_a" />
                <ColumnReference Database="[db_BA_LSA_QZ]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[fct_foo]" Column="col_b" />
              </OutputList>
              <RunTimeInformation>
                <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="1992" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
              </RunTimeInformation>
              <Sequence>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="9" EstimateCPU="1.157E-06" EstimateIO="0" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Table-valued function" NodeId="1" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Table-valued function" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="1.157E-06">
                  <OutputList />
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRebinds="1" ActualRewinds="0" ActualRows="0" ActualEndOfScans="0" ActualExecutions="1" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <TableValuedFunction>
                    <DefinedValues />
                    <Object Database="[db_BA_LSA_QZ]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[fct_foo]" />
                    <ParameterList>
                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[@buffer]">
                        <Identifier>
                          <ColumnReference Column="@buffer" />
                        </Identifier>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                      <ScalarOperator ScalarString="[@day]">
                        <Identifier>
                          <ColumnReference Column="@day" />
                        </Identifier>
                      </ScalarOperator>
                    </ParameterList>
                  </TableValuedFunction>
                </RelOp>
                <RelOp AvgRowSize="4575" EstimateCPU="0.0001581" EstimateIO="0.003125" EstimateRebinds="0" EstimateRewinds="0" EstimatedExecutionMode="Row" EstimateRows="1" LogicalOp="Table Scan" NodeId="4" Parallel="false" PhysicalOp="Table Scan" EstimatedTotalSubtreeCost="0.0032831" TableCardinality="0">
                  <OutputList>
                    <ColumnReference Database="[db_BA_LSA_QZ]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[fct_foo]" Column="col_a" />
                    <ColumnReference Database="[db_BA_LSA_QZ]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[fct_foo]" Column="col_b" />
                  </OutputList>
                  <RunTimeInformation>
                    <RunTimeCountersPerThread Thread="0" ActualRows="1992" ActualEndOfScans="1" ActualExecutions="1" />
                  </RunTimeInformation>
                  <TableScan Ordered="false" ForcedIndex="false" ForceScan="false" NoExpandHint="false">
                    <DefinedValues>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[db_BA_LSA_QZ]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[fct_foo]" Column="col_a" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                      <DefinedValue>
                        <ColumnReference Database="[db_BA_LSA_QZ]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[fct_foo]" Column="col_b" />
                      </DefinedValue>
                    </DefinedValues>
                    <Object Database="[db_BA_LSA_QZ]" Schema="[dbo]" Table="[fct_foo]" />
                  </TableScan>
                </RelOp>
              </Sequence>
            </RelOp>
            <ParameterList>
              <ColumnReference Column="@day" ParameterRuntimeValue="'2018-03-09'" />
              <ColumnReference Column="@buffer" ParameterRuntimeValue="(5.500000000000000e+001)" />
            </ParameterList>
          </QueryPlan>
        </StmtSimple>
      </Statements>
    </Batch>
  </BatchSequence>
</ShowPlanXML>
```

Comment: What makes you think it is being executed twice? The top part is the function being executed and filling the table variable declared as the function return type, the bottom part is the table variable being selected from. BTW interleaved execution will make the estimates there accurate once released. But what does the function do anyway? Can you make it inline instead of multi statement?

Comment: @MartinSmith is right, that function isn't being executed twice, but that plan does seem to imply it's a multi-line table function, not an inline table function. Posting your query, and the SQL for your function is going to be very helpful here.

Comment: Thank you for telling me it's not executed twice, this did really upset me. Still the function takes 7 times longer, when executed inside the function. i will post the code tomorrow.

Comment: sp_recompile did the job.