# SQL Server execution speed varies wildly depending on how parameters are provided to an inline table function

Tags: sql-server, sql-execution-plan

I am investigating a problem with the execution speed of an inline table function in SQL Server. Or that's where I thought the problem lay. I came across

[T-SQL code is extremely slow when saved as an Inline Table-valued Function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10017793/t-sql-code-is-extremely-slow-when-saved-as-an-inline-table-valued-function)

which looked promising, since it described what I was seeing, but I seemed to have the opposite problem - when I passed variables to my function, it took 17 seconds, but when I ran the code of my function in a query window, using DECLARE statements for the variables (which I thought effectively made them literals), it ran in milliseconds. Same code, same parameters - just wrapping them up in an inline table function seemed to drag it way down.

I tried to reduce my query to the minimum possible code that still exhibited the behaviour. I am using numerous existing inline table functions (all of which have worked fine for years), and managed to strip my code down to needing just a call of one existing inline table function to be able to highlight the speed difference. But in doing so I noticed something very odd

```
SELECT strStudentNumber
FROM dbo.udfNominalSnapshot('2019', 'REG')
```

takes 17 seconds whereas

```
DECLARE @strAcademicSessionStart varchar(4) = '2019'
DECLARE  @strProgressCode varchar(12)= 'REG'

SELECT strStudentNumber
FROM dbo.udfNominalSnapshot(@strAcademicSessionStart, @strProgressCode)
```

takes milliseconds! So nothing to do with wrapping the code in an inline table function, but everything to do with how the parameters are passed to a nested function within it. Based on the cited article I'm guessing there are two different execution plans in play, but I have no idea why/how, and more importantly, what I can do to persuade SQL Server to use the efficient one?

P.S. here is the code of the inner UDF call in response to a comment request

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udfNominalSnapshot] 
(   
    @strAcademicSessionStart varchar(4)='%',
        @strProgressCode varchar(10)='%'
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN 
(
SELECT     TOP 100 PERCENT S.strStudentNumber, S.strSurname, S.strForenames, S.strTitle, S.strPreviousSurname, S.dtmDoB, S.strGender, S.strMaritalStatus, 
                      S.strResidencyCode, S.strNationalityCode, S.strHESAnumber, S.strSLCnumber, S.strPreviousSchoolName, S.strPreviousSchoolCode, 
                      S.strPreviousSchoolType, 
                      COLLEGE_EMAIL.strEmailAddress AS strEmailAlias, 
                      PERSONAL_EMAIL.strEmailAddress AS strPersonalEmail,
                      P.[str(Sub)Plan], P.intYearOfCourse, P.strProgressCode, 
                      P.strAcademicSessionStart, strC2Knumber AS C2K_ID, AcadPlan,  strC2KmailAlias
                      ,ISNULL([strC2KmailAlias], [strC2Knumber]) + '@c2kni.net' AS strC2KmailAddress

FROM         dbo.tblStudents AS S
                      LEFT JOIN
                      dbo.udfMostRecentEmail('COLLEGE') AS COLLEGE_EMAIL ON S.strStudentNumber = COLLEGE_EMAIL.strStudentNumber
                      LEFT JOIN
                      dbo.udfMostRecentEmail('PERSONAL') AS PERSONAL_EMAIL ON S.strStudentNumber = PERSONAL_EMAIL.strStudentNumber
                       INNER JOIN
                      dbo.udfProgressHistory(@strAcademicSessionStart) AS P ON S.strStudentNumber = P.strStudentNumber
WHERE     (P.strProgressCode LIKE @strProgressCode OR (SUBSTRING(@strProgressCode, 1, 1) = '^' AND P.strProgressCode NOT LIKE SUBSTRING(@strProgressCode, 2, LEN(@strProgressCode)))) AND 
(P.strStudentNumber NOT IN
                          (SELECT     strStudentNumber
                            FROM          dbo.tblPilgrims
                            WHERE      (strAcademicSessionStart = @strAcademicSessionStart) AND (strScheme = 'BEI')))
ORDER BY P.[str(Sub)Plan], P.intYearOfCourse, S.strSurname
)
```

Comment: Is it `varchar(4) = 2019` or `int = 2019`?

Comment: have you had a look at the execution plans for both queries? it is not uncommon for SQL server to have cached multiple plans for one query unless you use forced parameters. This could also be a parameter sniffing issue. Please see the following link: https://www.brentozar.com/sql/parameter-sniffing/

Comment: the value 2019 is a varchar, I guess it should be in quotes but SQL seems happy enough, passing it quoted as '2019' in the slow version doesn't make any difference

Comment: I haven't looked at execution plans, and hope I don't have to, I know nothing about them

Comment: @DJDave, tbh I think that is going to be the only way to determine what the different is between the queries, to me this sounds like Parameter sniffing and the link above has some very good articles about it. Especially - https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2016/11/query-sometimes-fast-sometimes-slow/.

Comment: Also can you share the function?

Comment: I've watched part of the Brent Ozar vid. Surely it can't be a parameter sniffing issue if the parameters are the same in the two different examples?

Comment: Your examples aren't the same though. In example 1, you are passing in an integer value for the year and example 2 a string.

Comment: I've amended the question to eliminate the discrepancy in types - and re-run the queries to check that it has made no difference

Comment: I didn't share the function simply because I thought it would be a red herring, and I still think that, but I will update the question according to your request

Comment: Can you paste the plans here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/? and share it here?

Comment: slow
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SyuWQ5y_r

Comment: fast
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HJznf91dH

Comment: udfProgressHistory looks like it must be very complex. There are four separate clustered index scans just for that one table.

Comment: I still can't get past the fact that the same code runs in next-to-no-time just by calling it differently? So any nested routine can't be the critical factor?

Comment: @DJDave Parameter sniffing means that SQL Server can look over all your code before running any of it. But it's not a programmer. Seeing `dbo.udfNominalSnapshot('2019', 'REG')`, it can be positive that you're passing in '2019' and 'REG' as parameters, and it chooses a plan that it (apparently wrongly) thinks is optimized for those parameters. But to know that `dbo.udfNominalSnapshot(@strAcademicSessionStart, @strProgressCode)` is using the same values assigned above, it would have to be positive that no lines between could possibly change the variable. [continued]

Comment: [continued] But the optimizer isn't up to analyzing the flow control of every line, so it doesn't do that. (At least in your version of SQL Server -- maybe 2019 takes it a step further.)

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on @Ross Pressers comment, this might not really be an answer, but demonstrates what is happening (a bit), with my understanding (which could be wrong!) of what is happening...

Run the setup code at the end and then....

Execute the following with query plan on (Ctrl-M)... (note: depending on the random number generator you may or may not get any results, that does not affect the plan)

```
declare @one varchar(100) = '379', @two varchar(200) = '726'
select * from wibble(@one, @two)  -- 1 
select * from wibble('379', '726') -- 2
select * from wibble(@one, @two) OPTION (RECOMPILE) -- 3
select * from wibble(@one, @two)  -- 4
```

Caveat. The following is what happens on *MY* system, your mileage may vary...

-- 1 (and -- 4) are the most expensive.

SQL Server creates a generic plan as it does not know what the parameters are (yes they are defined, but the plan is for wibble(@one, @two) where, at that point, the parameter values are "unknown")
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJtIRwx_r

-- 2 has a different plan

Here, sql server knows what the parameters are, so can create a specific plan, which is quite different to --1
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rJa9APldS

-- 3 has the same plan as --2

Testing this further, adding OPTION (RECOMPILE) gets SQL Server to create a specific plan for the specific execution of wibble(@one, @two) so we get the same plan as --2

--4 is there for completeness to show that after all that mucking about the generic plan is still in place

So, in this simple example we have a parameterised TVF being called with identical values, that are passed either as parameters or inline, producing different execution plans and different execution times as per the OP

### Set up

```
use tempdb
GO

drop table if EXISTS Orders 
GO


create table Orders (
    OrderID int primary key,
    UserName varchar(50),
    PhoneNumber1 varchar(50),
)

-- generate 300000 with randon "phone" numbers

;WITH TallyTable AS (
SELECT TOP 300000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS [N]
  FROM dbo.syscolumns tb1,dbo.syscolumns tb2 
)
insert into Orders
select n, 'user' + cast(n as varchar(10)), cast(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(3) as int)
FROM TallyTable;


GO
drop function if exists wibble
GO

create or alter function wibble (
    @one varchar(4) = '%'
    , @two varchar(4) = '%'

)
returns table
as
return select * from Orders
where PhoneNumber1 like '%' + @one + '%'
and PhoneNumber1 like '%' + @two + '%'
or (SUBSTRING(@one, 1, 1) = '^' AND PhoneNumber1 NOT LIKE SUBSTRING(@two, 2, LEN(@two)))
and (select 1) = 1

GO
```

Comment: I think this is a good illustration of how/why the behaviour highlighted in the question occurs

Answer (score 1):

Problem was overcome (I wouldn't say "fixed") by following up on Ross Presser's observation about the complexity of udfProgressHistory. This sucked data from a table tblProgressHistory which was joined to itself. The table is added to annually. I think this year's additional 2K records must have caused the sudden cost-hike when using a particular execution plan. I deleted >2K redundant records and we're back to sub-second execution.